# zmq.connect() function failing for ipc transport on windows 7

Tags: javascript, node.js, zeromq

I'm working through the examples in 'Node.js the Right Way' and when executing the Router-Dealer example in Chapter 4 on Windows 7 with node.js version v0.10.29 , I get this error
`Protocol not supported` 
when executing

```
 let responder = zmq.socket('rep').connect('ipc://filer-dealer.ipc');
```

I have read many entries on the 0MQ site, and the only hint I have is that the ipc file `filer-dealer.ipc` is not being created since I can't find it.  The description of IPC indicates if the directory does not exist, an error is thrown. In this case, the file should be created in the directory where the `.js` files are.
There have been other examples in the book that require a file be read, and I rewrote an example to write new contents to a file so it doesn't appear to be read/write permissions.
I've looked in the book errata, but no mention was made.
Any idea where to look? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

ZeroMQ IPC transport is not supported on windows, use tcp instead.